# Entity Framework Code First with an existing database

Tags: entity-framework

I have to create a new project and (as usual) is with an existing SQL Server database.

I used to use EF Code First connecting with my database, opening my EDMX model designer and then right click --> Add Code Generation Item. (http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/02/24/generating-ef-code-first-model-classes-from-an-existing-database.aspx) Easy.

But now I've discovered there's something called EF Power Tools that allows me to do Reverse Engineer Code First (cool name!) and get the same (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620)

Do you know the difference between the two options? Which one is better?

Thanks in advance.

(Sorry if this question was previously asked but I didn't find it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the edmx approach is not code first, but database first with `DbContext` API. You will always use the database as the source of model changes.

EF Power Tools produce a truly code first model with `DbContext`: from then on you will change the class model first and modify the database accordingly (e.g. by EF migrations).

Neither is "better". `DbContext` API is easier to work with than `ObjectContext`, but both approaches use the former. It's up to you to choose whether you want to work database first or code first. It's a matter of personal preference and it may depend on who maintains the database structure. With database first it is easier to respond to changes someone else imposes on the database structure.

Comment: Thanks very much Gert. It's possible that the new application will be done creating a new database instead to use the old one. Do you think in this possible new scenario would be better to use EF Code First to create the classes and let EF to create my database?

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer code first. But it's really a matter of taste!

Answer (score 1):

As far as workflow goes for database first, adding to what @Gert-Arnold said:

> With database first it is easier to respond to changes someone else imposes on the database structure.

If someone else is managing the database changes, I'm finding it far easier to use the EF Designer.  You get an updated database, then just right-click in the EF Designer and update the model from the database.  You can use source control to easily view what has changed.

Also, if you only need a subset of tables from the database, reverse engineering causes alot of work having to go back and remove classes and properties from the context.

I found re-reverse engineering via code-first to an existing database to be just too much of a pain trying to figure out what changed and how I needed to update code that used the context.